# Row_Number and Partition

Tags: sql

My data looks like this -

```
CALENDAR    CLIENTID
20180801    178
20180802    178
20180803    578
```

The `max(calendar)` for `clientid` `178` is `20180802`. How do I get the row_number for `max(calendar)` per `clientid`. In the case of client `178`, it would be 2 because it is the second row. This is what I have so far -

```
 select clientid, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by clientid ORDER BY max(calendar) desc )
 from STATS
 group by clientid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just count the rows for each client:

```
select clientid, count(*)
from stats
group by clientid;
```

This is the maximum of the "row number".